# How to place the legends on the top of the figure in python plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, charts, plotly

I use python's `plotly` to produce a figure. I want to legends (the two small squares in the top right) to be place on the top  of the char due to space limitations in the width.

[image: here is the imag]

Can anyone point to me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fig.update_layout(legend=dict(y=1.1, orientation='h'))` to put your legend just above the charting area and make it horizontal:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `fig.update_layout(legend=dict(x, y))` to specify where the legend sits. `x` and `y` are in relation to the x and y axis

Comment: When I tried: `fig.update_layout(legend=dict(50,50))`, I got this error: `TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: try it with `fig.update_layout(legend=dict(x = 50,y = 50))`

Comment: oh yeah sorry, i removed the numbers to try to make it more clear, but i might have made it harder to understand. @vbrises 's answer should work. Though `x=50,y=50` might be too much; e.g. way off the figure. you could try `x=1.1,y=1.1` if that happens.